# TCPDF_PARSER ERROR: Invalid object reference: Array

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, pdfparser

I'm using library [PDFparser](https://www.pdfparser.org/) (https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser) to convert PDF file to text.

When I try to convert a file on a local web-server, it parses OK. When I try to convert a file on remote web-server, it fails with the following error: `TCPDF_PARSER ERROR: Invalid object reference: Array`.

I couldn't find a proper solution in the bug-tracker of a library, although there is exist the similar question (it didn't solved for two years).

How can I avoid this error? Or should I use another library for converting pdf to text (which)?

I am using it straight as mentioned in documentation:

```
use Smalot\PdfParser\Parser;

$this->parser = new Parser;

if (file_exists($full_path) && !is_dir($full_path)) {
    $paper->text = $this->parser->parseFile($full_path)->getText();
}
```

Comment: WTF dude! How can anyone know with no code?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, added code, sorry :)

Comment: You need to make sure your PDF is 1.4 or lower. This means roughly Acrobat 5 compatible.

Comment: @hcoat, but on local web-server it converts even PDF1.7. On remote server - it fails on PDF1.3! (and on 1.4 and on 1.7)

Comment: @АлександрЧи That is odd. I guess I would suggest using composer to upgrade packages or reinstall. Also make sure you are running the same version of PHP on both machines with the same extensions.

Comment: Do you check if the PDF is not corrupted? A site to verify: https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx

Comment: The fix on this page was useful for me with a case like yours: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/issues/86